# In DjangoRestFramework, is it expected that a MultipleChoiceField default attribute is ignored?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following request serializer using a MultipleChoiceField

```
class CompletedOrderStatusDefault:
    requires_context = False

    def __call__(self, serializer_field):
        # -----> this code is never hit?!
        return [OrderStatus.COMPLETED]

class OrderListRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
...
    order_statuses = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        default=CompletedOrderStatusDefault(),
        choices=AllowedOrderStatus.ALLOWED,
    )
```

the code in the call is never hit during a request and the value for the field is instead an empty set. Is this a bug I should raise or am I wrong to expect that the default is used for this MultipleChoiceField? if so, how should the default be set when the parameter is unspecified in an incoming request?

Answer (score 0):

Classes are not callable but their instances are, when the `__call__` method is implemented. So, you should pass in an instance of the class and not the class itself:

```
order_statuses = serializers.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        default=CompletedOrderStatusDefault(),
        choices=AllowedOrderStatus.ALLOWED,
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, I had transcribed incorrectly and have edited, but it still doesn't trigger the function to be called - the default appears ignored. I'm presuming this is either a bug with DRF or a bad expectation on my part.

Comment: Most likely something is wrong somewhere else in your code. If you check the answer to the linked question you will see that it was also done this way